# How to read a file in PHP, then write only certain lines back out to another file

Tags: php, file

I have a simple text file (it's an m3u8 playlist) on SERVER A.  On server B, I need to have a PHP script that reads the playlist file, then writes only certain lines from it to a new file on Server B.

I can open the file via file_get_contents just fine, and even write it out to a new file just fine.  But I'm stuck figuring out how to take only certain lines from the file.  An entire example playlist file is below.  It will always be exactly the same number of lines and same format:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=678000,RESOLUTION=768x432,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_678_av-p.m3u8? sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=198000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.66.30, mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_198_av-p.m3u8?sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2320000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_2320_av-p.m3u8?sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=48000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_198_a-p.m3u8?sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
```

In the example above, I want to write out a new file with lines 1,2,3,6,7, so the new file would look like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=678000,RESOLUTION=768x432,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_678_av-p.m3u8? sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2320000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.2"
link://me.akamaihd.net/i/242049_1978582_00713dc8_1@105175/index_2320_av-p.m3u8?sd=10&dw=100&rebase=on
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Consider `file()` to get an array of lines and either `preg_grep()` or a loop for skipping or slicing out just the desired lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file` to read the file into an **array**, then specify those exact lines to create an output array which you will [write to a text file](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/file_write_php.htm).

```
<?php

$file = file('yourfile.txt');
$output = array();

$lines_you_want = array(1, 2, 3, 6, 7);

foreach($lines_you_want as $line_no) {
    $output[] = $file[$line_no - 1]; // array keys start from zero, not 1
}

// write $output array to file
// if you want $output as a \n delimited string, implode it:
// $output = implode("\n", $output);

?>
```

Docs: http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Cool, was able to get this working in a few minutes with a little trial and error. Even a complete novice like me got it.  Thanks!

Comment: Scrowler how i can create hyperlink for each RESOLUTION found in playlist and output those hyperlinks?